# CellValueChanged vs CellValidating Events for DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

What's the best place to implement validation logic code and conditional formatting code for a DataGridView?

In a lot of books and articles that I've read on this control, it seems to suggest that the appropriate event to handle for this is the CellValidating one.
Well, the name more than implies this as well.

However, this event triggers a bit too often for my tastes and I'm not sure it is required.
For example, this event triggers everytimes the users switches to another row.

On the other hand, the CellValueChanged event seems to trigger only when the value of the cell changes, which means the validation code runs only when the value changes and not everytime a user changes cells.

Now, since so many books use the CellValidating event, I wonder if there is not any gotcha (in display for example) with using the CellValueChanged?

I understand that the impact in performance should be irrelevant when using simple validation and conditional highlighting rules but I would as much prefer it not to run useless code everytime the user moves to another cell if it can be avoided.

Thanks,

Comment: Depends on what design pattern (if any) you are following. Technically speaking you should remove your business logic away from your UI layer and have some sort of ValidationObject to validate the data in your presentation layer and then post back the results to your view.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with that if it is for validation only. However, for conditional formatting code, I don't see much other way for it to remain in DataGridView's related-code (or in a class derived from DataGridView to abstract it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using CellValueChanged currently on a grid with custom validation and have had no problems with display or anything else.

I used this event because I wanted to fire off a certain order of events, but only when the user changes the value of a cell.

I have not noticed much in the way of a performance hit (tested with 100 - 5000 rows).

I think in the end it depends on what your validation needs are. In my case, CellValueChanged has done what I wanted/needed.

**EDIT**

The biggest thing about the CellValidating event is that you can stop the user from leaving a cell, if the value entered does not pass your validation. I didn't want to do this.

Comment: Thanks, good point about CellValidating allowing to stop the user from leaving the cell. Not something I need in my current project but I don't think I remembered this difference.

Comment: I don't want to stop the user leaving the cell if it doesnt pass validation.  Can you give me an example of your CellValueChanged function?  Right now I'm using CellValidating, CellValidated, and CellEndEdit.  But I think your method is the best.  If you can provide and example it would help a lot.

Comment: "CellValidating event is that you can stop the user from leaving a cell" which also prevents user from closing the Form. Not good practice, but can be useful in particular situation.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple, inside the CellValidatingEvent you need to check if a condition is right. If your condition is false then you just add this code `e.cancel`. It will prevent the cursor to lost its focus