# DataGridView How to Validate&Select cell

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have a grid view contains multiple columns and I adjusted their input type to be `double`.

When the user selects a cell, enters its data, I want to check if it matches the type of `double`.

If the user clicks on another cell and the one he is about to leave doesn't match and it failed in parsing, I want the focus return to the failed cell, and not moving to the new selected one, to force the user to enter a valid data before continuing filling the rest of the cells.

The problem is that it always leaves the failed cell. Even when I used other functions like validating or validated.

Here is my code sample:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            var selectedCell = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0];
            if (selectedCell.OwningColumn.ValueType == typeof(double))
            {
                try
                {
                    double result = Convert.ToDouble(selectedCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());
                    if (result <= 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Positive Numbers Only");
                        dataGridView1.Focus();
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[selectedCell.RowIndex].Cells[selectedCell.ColumnIndex];
                        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = result;
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Numbers Only");
                } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use event `DataGridView.CellValidating`. This should fix your problem.

**Example:**

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, 
                                           DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) // 1 should be your column index
        {
            int i;

            if (!int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(e.FormattedValue), out i))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                label1.Text ="please enter numeric";
            }
            else
            {
                // the input is numeric 
            }
        }
    }
```

[DataGridView.CellValidating Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx)

[How to: Validate Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-validate-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

[CellValueChanged vs CellValidating Events for DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469582/cellvaluechanged-vs-cellvalidating-events-for-datagridview)

Comment: Did you try it and it works? please provide me with a sample code because I tried it and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Yes it's working like charm. Dgv "CellValidating", rises when you intend to leave actual cell (or click on some other cell, or pressing enter).

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to add this line `e.Cancel = true;` when I used CellValidating. Now it works perfectly.